# How to navigate between other navHost

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

**My Root Graph**

```
@Composable
fun RootNavigationGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = RootScreen.Welcome.route
    ) {
        welcomeGraph(navController)
        authGraph(navController)
        composable(route = RootScreen.Main.route) {
            MainScreen()
        }
        trackingGraph(navController)
    }
}
```

**My Main Graph**

this for bottom navigation

```
@Composable
fun MainNavigationGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = RootScreen.Dashboard.route,
        route = RootScreen.Main.route
    ) {
        dashboardGraph(navController)
        orderGraph(navController)
        profileGraph(navController)
    }
}
```

**My Composable View**

This code inside DashboardScreen that wrap in dashboardGraph
@Composable
fun FeatureCardList(items: List, navController: NavController) {

```
    LazyRow(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)) {
        items(items) { menus ->
            FeatureCardItemSingle(
                item = menus,
                onClick = {
                    Log.d("FeatureCardList", "Clicked item: ${menus.move_to}")
                    navController.navigate(RootScreen.Tracking.route)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use nested navigation graph

```
@Composable
fun RootNavigationGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = RootScreen.Welcome.route,
        nestedNavGraphs = listOf(
            NavGraph(
                route = RootScreen.Main.route,
                startDestination = RootScreen.Dashboard.route
            ) {
                mainGraph(navController)
            }
        )
    ) {
        welcomeGraph(navController)
        authGraph(navController)
        composable(route = RootScreen.Main.route) {
            MainScreen()
        }
        trackingGraph(navController)
    }
}
```

then navigate in your card

```
@Composable
fun FeatureCardList(items: List<Menu>, navController: NavController) {
    LazyRow(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)) {
        items(items) { menu ->
            FeatureCardItemSingle(
                item = menu,
                onClick = {
                    Log.d("FeatureCardList", "Clicked item: ${menu.move_to}")
                    navController.navigate(RootScreen.Main.route + "/${RootScreen.Tracking.route}")
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the 

  nestedNavGraphs = listOf(
            NavGraph(
                route = RootScreen.Main.route,
                startDestination = RootScreen.Dashboard.route
            ) {
                mainGraph(navController)
            }
        )

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/tracking_detail/RSIL2023082810600041/2023082810600028 } cannot be found in the navigation graph ComposeNavGraph(0x177b2ebb) route=main_root startDestination={ComposeNavGraph(0xf4c7f07a) route=dashboard_root startDestination={Destination(0x78d845ec) route=home}}